# How can a custom Xamarin.Forms theme specify a page's background color?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a custom theme following https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/themes/custom/, but it is unclear how a page's background color can be set via the theme.

I've tried creating an implicit style targeting a ContentPage. I've also tried creating a style class for the ContentPage. Neither works. It doesn't work since the actual page being loaded isn't a ContentPage, but rather subclassed page. In https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27659 Jason Smith states "Implicit styles do not apply to subclasses."

I'd love to take a look at the Xamarin.Forms.Themes source to see how the Forms team does it, but it doesn't appear to be available on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @JoshuaLatusia said:
>   Hi, I found this to be working for all my pages.
>   By using "ApplyToDerivedTypes" you will set a generic style for all your Content pages.
>   Example:
>
> `<Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
>     <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#eeecf6" />
>   </Style>`

See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/302323/#Comment_302323